Spring WebClient map operation/functionality
How does the map operation from WebClient do the mapping?
Given that example:
client.get()
        .uri("/quotes").accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(Quote.class);

When i want to convert Quote on the fly to BetterQuote for example:
client.get()
        .uri("/quotes").accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(Quote.class)
        .map(this::toBetterQuote);

The question here is:
Will all Quotes be fetched from a given API and then (if all are there) the map() will happen?
Or does the map() starts to happen immediatly when the first Quotes are coming in?
So will this iterate only once the whole Quotes?
Iterable<BetterQuote> betterQuotes = client.get()
        .uri("/quotes").accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(Quote.class)
        .map(this::toBetterQuote)
        .toIterable();

Whereas this iterates twice?
Iterable<Quote> betterQuotes = client.get()
        .uri("/quotes").accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(Quote.class)
        .toIterable();

Iterable<BetterQuote> moreBetter = betterQuotes.map(this::mapToBetterQuotes)

EDIT
I don´t mind if something is blocking in the first place, because i have a blocking database at the end of the line. Using WebClient is absolutely fine, even if i use it in blocking scenarios. I don´t want to pull in another 3rd party lib as suggested, since WebClient is there out of the box.
So to clarify my question i want to give an example:
Let's say, i have 1000 Quote records from a wep api.
Given this piece of code:
Iterable<BetterQuote> betterQuotes = client.get()
        .uri("/quotes").accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(Quote.class)
        .map(this::toBetterQuote)
        .toIterable();


Can i assume, that my 1000 Quotes will be fetched one by one, and then mapped to BetterQuotes  and then built to an Iterable by toIterable? So in sum, i have 1000 operations in line?

Or is it the case that ALL 1000 Quotes will be fetched, built to a List internally and then the map() operation happens on the internal List of already fetched 1000 Quotes?


So in case 2 i would have 2000 operations, 1000 x fetching the ?Quotes and 1000 x mapping to BetterQuotes

toIterable will return an iterable that is blocking on each onNext call, meaning that as soon as you call map on it, it will block. So you are aware of this, and that is forbidden in a WebFlux application, as blocking is prohibited in NIO threads. And Webflux in general does not iterate, you build a "pipeline" whereas map will call onNext, on the previous operator. You are dealing with infinite pipes here. Not finite lists. the toIterable returns a lazy iterable (not a list, something you can iterate over) meaning nothing happens until you actually start doing things on it as the docs says

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#toIterable-int-java.util.function.Supplier-

It doesn't make sense to use a reactive WebClient if you later convert it to a non-reactive execution with .toIterable(). It would be more effective to either stay within reactive (i.e., no .toIterable() or similar) or use a non-reactive client (ex. Apache HTTP Client, etc)
